# How to free up Memory? Deleting drawables after using

Tags: android

I have three view flippers with different images in each flipper.
I need to free up the memory once I close one flipper.
I can open each flipper individually but when I open a flipper and open another one the "OutofMemory" Error shows up.

I tried deleting the viewflipper after using it but I read that that doesn't work since the drawables has already been loaded or something along those lines.

How could I free up memory?

Thank you for anyone that could help. And sorry for my english

Comment: Show us what you have done in code or tried?